# Running Cursor Pause/Play Audio Matlab UI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am currently working on a vertical moving cursor than goes along with the sound while playing a wav signal. It works fine alone, but as soon as I try to link it to my Play/Pause button, it fails. I have found that using 'uiwait' and 'uiresume' may be useful but despite my efforts, I can't make that line pausing and playing when ever i want.

My callback for the Play/Pause Toggle button is here :

```
`% --- Executes on button press in play_pauseTogglebutton.
function play_pauseTogglebutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to play_pauseTogglebutton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
linePlaying(handles.current_data);
if isplaying(handles.sound)
    pause(handles.sound)
    %c_sample = get(handles.sound,'CurrentSample');
    %disp(c_sample)
    handles.pause=1;
else
    if(handles.pause==1)
    resume(handles.sound);
    handles.pause=0;
    else
    play(handles.sound);
    handles.pause=0;
    end
end
% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of play_pauseTogglebutton
% Save the handles structure.
guidata(hObject,handles)`
```

My method that makes my line Playing is :

```
`function linePlaying(current_data)
[y,fs]=wavread(current_data);
h=line([0,0],       [min(min(y)),max(max(y))],'color','b','Marker','*','MarkerEdgeColor','b','LineStyle','-','linewidth',2);
end_time=length(y)/fs;
tic
t=toc;
while (t<end_time)
    set(h,'xdata',t*[1,1])
    drawnow
    t=toc;
end
end`
```

Thank you for reading, I hope someone can help me :)

PS:I am as much a newbie to Matlab than I am in English.

**EDIT**

Screenshot of the GUI:

[image]

THANK YOU :)

The Pause button makes the line stops. But I still have a problem : The line goes way to fast and changing the unit step in the set function changes nothing...
Here is my code with your system of plotting the line :

```
% --- Executes on button press in togglebutton1.
function togglebutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
AxisLim = axis;
ispushed=get(hObject,'Value');
if ispushed
    set(hObject,'String','pause')
    if(handles.pause==0)
        play(handles.sound);
    else
        resume(handles.sound);
    end
    while true

                LinePos = ceil(get(handles.L,'XData'));

                %// If the line reaches the axes limit, go back to start.
                if LinePos(1) == AxisLim(2)

                    set(handles.L,'XData',[1 1]);

                    %// drawnow is important!!
                    drawnow
                else

                %// Update position of th eline
                set(handles.L,'XData',[LinePos(1)+1 LinePos(2)+1])
                drawnow
                end

                %// If stop button was pressed, stop.
                if strcmp(get(hObject,'String'),'play')
                    break
                end

            end
    handles.pause=0;
else
    set(hObject,'String','play')
    pause(handles.sound);
    handles.pause=1;
end

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Comment: Sounds interesting! Can you provide a screenshot of what the UI looks like? I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "goes along with the sound...". You can post a link to an external website and somebody here will add it to your question. Thanks!

Comment: http://imgur.com/nsLj5wT

Comment: The blue line is moving. I hope it's a little bit more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Yes thanks a lot! I added the image to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. Basically I use the `String` property of the Play/Stop pushbutton to toggle the display of the moving line. In this example I use a static image but that will be the same with your data.

The code is commented; please try it out and if something is unclear just ask!

Create a new .m file with the following code:

```
function MoveSliderGUI
clc
clear all

global PlayStrings L
hFig = figure('Position',[100 100 400 400],'Units','normalized');

handles.axes1 = axes('Units','normalized','Position',[.2 .2 .6 .6]);

%// Create cell array with 2 strings.
PlayStrings = {'Play';'Stop'};

handles.PlayStopButton= uicontrol('Style','push','String',PlayStrings{1},'Position',[40 350 50 30],'Callback',@(s,e) PlayStopCallback);

handles.img = imread('peppers.png');

[~,NumCol,~] = size(handles.img);

imshow(handles.img,'parent',handles.axes1)

%// Get axis limits
AxisLim = axis;

%// Draw line
L = line([AxisLim(1) AxisLim(1)],[AxisLim(3) AxisLim(4)],'color','b','Marker','*','MarkerEdgeColor','b','LineStyle','-','linewidth',2);

guidata(hFig,handles);


    function PlayStopCallback(~,~)

        handles = guidata(hFig);

        %// Check current string in pushbutton
        if strcmp(get(handles.PlayStopButton,'String'),'Play')
            set(handles.PlayStopButton,'String','Stop')

            while true

                LinePos = ceil(get(L,'XData'));

                %// If the line reaches the axes limit, go back to start.
                if LinePos(1) == NumCol

                    set(L,'XData',[1 1]);

                    %// drawnow is important!!
                    drawnow
                else

                %// Update position of th eline
                set(L,'XData',[LinePos(1)+1 LinePos(2)+1])
                drawnow
                end

                %// If stop button was pressed, stop the movie.
                if strcmp(get(handles.PlayStopButton,'String'),'Play')
                    break
                end

            end

        else
            set(handles.PlayStopButton,'String','Play')
        end

        guidata(hFig,handles);
    end

end
```

Here is a screen recording of what it looks like:

[image]

You can then synchronize the "playing" of your sound file with the line moving. Good luck!

**EDIT**

I used `[~,c,~] = size(handles.im)` to get the dimensions of the axes in which the image was displayed. In your case, this will likely be ~12, i.e. the upper bound of your x-axis. Depending on the units of the axes it might be pixels or normalized units.

The command

```
AxisLimits = axis
```

will give you a 4-element vector telling you `[x_min x_max y_min y_max]` for the current axes.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are litteraly god-sent. What should I put instead of [~,NumCol,~] = size(handles.img) ? [~,NumCol,~] = length(y)/fs doesn't work. I know why^^But i don't know what to put instead. It may be possible if I use a timer, but i don't know how to pause it when the Pause button is on. Thank you again

Comment: hahaha wow thanks for that! You can mark the answer as "accepted" if it helped you...which I think it does :) Have fun!

Comment: I edit the answer (at the bottom) that should help you with that :)

Comment: The Line stops well at the end, thank you. But it goes way to fast, it's not sync with the audio signal. I can't upload my code because it's too long in the comment section.

Comment: Oh I had not thought of that. You could try reducing the step size of the line (in my example it goes 1 unit right at every iteration of the loop)...mhh I'll think about that!

Comment: I figured out the problem of the play/pause button, still struggling with the high speed of the line...thank you if you can help

Comment: Yes sorry if I didn't respond earlier; I don't have much time until tomorrow so I'll try and look at this over the weekend.

Comment: Maybe I should increase the step of the plot, the line seems to go by steps of one second, but very fast...or try to use a timer...

Comment: Mhh yes I though about pausing the animation but since we only want to slow the line down (and not the sound playing) that's quite tricky...I'll keep thinking about it!